# ajax - request object readyState not changing

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, servlets

I have this function in ajax which receives the server response , but it is not entering in the first if :

```
function handleServerResponseForDesignations(ele){

        var attrName = ele.getAttribute("name");
        console.log("Attribute name : "+attrName);
        console.log("in handleServerResponseforDesignations");
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4){
            console.log("ready state is 4");
            if(xmlHttp.status == 200){
                var response2 = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
                console.log("response2 : "+JSON.stringify(response2));
                if(response2.status == "200" || response2.status == 200){
                    var designations = response2.designations;
                    for(var i = 0; i< designations.length; i++){
                        var temp = designations[i];
                        var newoption = document.createElement("option");
                        newoption.value = temp.emp_id;
                        newoption.innerHTML = temp.designation;
                        if(attrName == "sender_department"){
                            console.log("inside sender_department if");
                            document.getElementById("sender_designation").options.add(newoption);
                        }
                        else if(attrName == "recipient_department"){
                            console.log("inside recipient_department if");
                            document.getElementById("recipient_designation").options.add(newoption);    
                        }                       
                    }
                    return true;    
                }
            }
            else{
                alert("Connection Problem ! ! !");
            }
        }       
    }
```

it is printing in the console till : "in handleServerResponseforDesignations" but not going ahead. I am receiving a json as response and I checked on the server side , the json being sent is : ' responseValue : {"status":200,"designations":`[{"designation":"smm1","emp_id":"251235"},{"designation":"lpo","emp_id":"234567"}]}` .

The call happens whenever there is a change in combo box :

```
<select name="sender_department" id="sender_department" onchange="getDesignations(this)" disabled>
<option value="" disabled selected></option>
</select>
```

the function that makes the ajax call is :

```
        function getDesignations(ele){

        console.log("in getDesignations()");
        var val = ele.value;
        console.log("val is : "+val);
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 0 || xmlHttp.readyState == 4){
            department = encodeURIComponent(val);
            if(department === null || department === ""){
                return false;
            }
            xmlHttp.open("GET","GetDesignations?department="+department,true);
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponseForDesignations(ele);
            xmlHttp.send(null);
        }
        else{
            setTimeout('getDesignations(ele)',1000);
        }

    }
```

there is another function on the same page which is working fine. that also uses the same ajax object, but on a different event. I am using chrome Browser . please help !!

Comment: Are you on windows 8+ in IE or Chrome?

Comment: Check your readystate,  is it 0 ?

Comment: also, if you have a win7 computer, or try in firefox on win8+ can you check if it  works in either of those ?

Comment: So...clearly readyState is not 4 - so what is it instead?

Comment: I tried using || xmlHttp.readyState == 0 but then also it dint work !! :/

Comment: I just checked readyState is 1 :/

Comment: it is 1 , it is not null, please help !!

Comment: yeah i sent that before you posted the readystate...  should move this convo to chat....     readystate 1 means the ajax request has not been sent

Comment: does it work in firefox?  (Win 8+ in IE/Chrome has issues w ajax sometimes) Can you post the ajax request in your question,  and the code that is calling your function.

Comment: not working in firefox also , i guess the readystate 1 means server connection established , but it has not received the response from server yet ???

Comment: See my answer for the readystate.  1 means it has not been sent yet

Comment: wait, sorry i thought for some reason you were using jquery, are you just using javascript,  no jquery ?

Comment: yes i am using javascript

Comment: can you post the code that calls this function

Comment: i did edit the post. please check

Comment: well, remove the readystate == 0 of course

Comment: OK, I think I got it this time,  try my newest update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72536/discussion-between-notorious-pet0-and-furquan-ahmed).

Answer (score 0):

> The ajax requests are asynchronous, i.e., the response comes later and it seems that you are immediately calling the `handleServerResponseForDesignations` function. After the http request is complete, i.e., success(200/OK in your case) or failure(some HTTP error code), the `XMLHttpRequest` implementation will call the callback method: `onreadystatechange`. When the ready state changes, you will have the http response and response code available.
>   
>   Change your function as below and it should work:

```
    function handleServerResponseForDesignations(ele, xmlHttp) {

    var attrName = ele.getAttribute("name");
    console.log("Attribute name : " + attrName);
    console.log("in handleServerResponseforDesignations");

    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
        console.log("ready state is 4");
        if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            var response2 = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
            console.log("response2 : " + JSON.stringify(response2));
            if (response2.status == "200" || response2.status == 200) {
                var designations = response2.designations;
                for (var i = 0; i < designations.length; i++) {
                    var temp = designations[i];
                    var newoption = document.createElement("option");
                    newoption.value = temp.emp_id;
                    newoption.innerHTML = temp.designation;
                    if (attrName == "sender_department") {
                        console.log("inside sender_department if");
                        document.getElementById("sender_designation").options.add(newoption);
                    } else if (attrName == "recipient_department") {
                        console.log("inside recipient_department if");
                        document.getElementById("recipient_designation").options.add(newoption);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

        } else {
            alert("Connection Problem ! ! !");
        }
    }
}

    function getDesignations(ele) {

    console.log("in getDesignations()");
    var val = ele.value;
    console.log("val is : " + val);
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    department = encodeURIComponent(val);
    if (department === null || department === "") {
        return false;

        xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
           handleServerResponseForDesignations(ele, xmlHttp);
        }
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "GetDesignations?department=" + department, true);

        xmlHttp.send(null);
    } else {
        setTimeout('getDesignations(ele)', 1000);
    }

}
```

Comment: this function which you created , for me this handleServerResponseforDesignation is that function , .i.e this is the function that gets called when onreadystatechange changes

Comment: In that case, pass the `xmlHttp` object as an argument to this function. Also, do console.log(xmlHttp.readyState) and see what it prints.

Comment: xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponseForDesignations(ele, xmlhttp);
   
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);    
    xmlhttp.send();  
// Don't forget to open and send as above.

Comment: see in my post, thats what I am doing

Comment: Seems like you are trying to re-use the variable xmlhttp without re-instantiating it, also your order of things is wrong. You need to create the instance, set callback, open and then send.

You are not instantiating inside the getDesignations and also try changing in the order of setting the callback first and then open and send.

Comment: changing the order dint help, what happened is I got the previous response which I received while using xmlHttp in another function in this function, .i.e. I guess the readyState became ) now :/

Comment: If you re-use the same variable think of the scenario where the user changes the select box multiple times before the request is complete.

Also, you are checking for ready state to be 0 or 4 before making the ajax call, what if another call has changed the ready state to something else? Your subsequent changes in select box  will not spawn an ajax call at all.

Comment: yes , you are right, so now I did as you posted created a local xmlHttpRequest object and passed it , but now readyState is 0 and i am getting "connection problem" alert which I have put in my code.

Comment: Also, if you are not passing anything in the body, do not pass null in the xmlHttp.send method.

Comment: Isn't passing null same as doing this ?   xmlHttp.send() ??

Comment: Make the following change, it should work, you cannot 

         
 xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {

              handleServerResponseForDesignations(ele);
        } else {
              alert("Connection problem");
        }
          };

Comment: @NotoriousPet0: Something seems to have changed recently. [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#send())
So I just wanted to make sure that's not causing the issue.

Comment: w3schools would disagree with you http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_httprequest.asp